# Binding button programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some piece of code like this:

```
foreach (Sale s in sales)
{
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel { Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal };                      
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = s.Model + " " + s.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() });
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Удалить", Width = 55, Height = 20,FontSize=13 });//bind to this button
    databaseView.panelSale.Children.Add(new Expander
    {
        Name = "exp" + s.ID,
        Header =sp,
        Content = new SaleView { DataContext = s }
    });
}
break;
```

and some method:

```
private void DeleteSale(Sale sale)
{
    try
    {
        db.Sales.Remove(sale);
        db.SaveChanges();    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The question is how to bind this method to button click that i created programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Just modifying this

```
sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = s.Model + " " + s.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() });
sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Удалить", Width = 55, Height = 20,FontSize=13 });
```

to

```
   sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = s.Model + " " + s.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() });
   Button btn = new Button { Content = "Удалить", Width = 55, Height = 20, FontSize = 13 }
   btn.Click += Btn_Click;
   sp.Children.Add(btn);

   //rest of your code
}

private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //pass methods or anything in this click event
   //eg:
   DeleteSale(sale); 
   // The above method expects a Sale parameter so pass it appropriately
}
```

---

So if you want to pass `Sale` from `foreach (Sale s in sales)` loop, you can do this:

```
foreach (Sale s in sales)
{
     //codes above as in your question
     Button btn = new Button { Content = "Удалить", Width = 55, Height = 20, FontSize = 13 }
     btn.Tag = s;
     btn.Click += Btn_Click;
     //codes below as in your question
}
```

And then in the `Btn_Click` event, do this:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Sale sale = (Sale)((Button)sender).Tag;
   DeleteSale(sale); 
}
```

Hope you got the idea. Moreover if your method takes parameters, you would have to take that into account as well like the above one

Answer (score -1):

You could hook up an event handler using the `+=` syntax an anonymous event handler:

```
foreach (Sale s in sales)
{
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = s.Model + " " + s.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() });
    Button button = new Button { Content = "Удалить", Width = 55, Height = 20, FontSize = 13 };
    button.Click += (ss, ee) => DeleteSale(s);
    sp.Children.Add(button);
    databaseView.panelSale.Children.Add(new Expander
    {
        Name = "exp" + s.ID,
        Header = sp,
        Content = new SaleView { DataContext = s }
    });
}
```